# Weird black lines when using support design library on a Samsung s3 mini

Tags: android, material-design, androiddesignsupport

I have a problem where these weird lines apear when I click on the Navigation hamburger menu or on any of the items in the navigation list.

This only apears to be happening on a Samsung GT-I8200 with Android 4.2.2. 
I dont get the problem on my Moto G 3rd with Android 6.0. 
I am using the support design library.

[image: Nav View]

[image: Hamburger icon]

Comment: Are you setting your own drawables on any of those items? That looks suspiciously like a 9-patch drawable that isn't formatted correctly or isn't being used correctly.

Comment: No I am not using any custom drawables, eveything is standard. Strangely when I installed one of the material design sample apps from play store everything works fine in those apps.